# Checking database connection using db.isOpen()

Tags: c++, sql, qt, connection

I tried to use:

```
if (!db.isOpen()) {
  db.open();
}
```

to check my db connection, but it wont reconnect to my database...:( My connection will randomly drop after opening my program for (20-30seconds?). However if I just forget about the if statement and do `db.open();` it works. I do have `#include <QSqlDatabase>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `isOpen` doesn't check if connection is still alive. It just returns true if connection was open successfully and has not been closed yet. You should check connection using a simple SQL request (e.g. `SELECT 1`). Also may be if you execute this request periodically, the connection will be kept alive.

See also [Detecting QSqlDatabase disconnections](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/45052-Detecting-QSqlDatabase-disconnections).